# How do I replace Ubuntu with Ubuntu studio on a dual boot system (Windows 8-32 bit and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-studio

How do I replace Ubuntu with Ubuntu studio on a dual boot system (Windows 8-32 bit and Ubuntu 11.04. I'm not a linux geek so I need some concise but simple instructions. I upgraded to Windows 8 from Vista. This is not a 64 bit computer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to replace Ubuntu with Ubuntu Studio is to get the latest or long-term support (LTS) Ubuntu Studio image (32-bit in your case), burn it to a DVD or USB stick (using Startup Disk Creator or Unetbootin), then boot from whichever you created.

When the opening screen appears, select "Install Ubuntu Studio." Proceed to select your installation language and make sure the requirements are met (whether or not you are connected to the Internet makes no difference). When you are asked how to install Ubuntu Studio, **select "Replace Ubuntu  with Ubuntu Studio."** After that, set your time zone, layout, and user info, then sit back and relax as Ubuntu Studio installs.